# POCO class in nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, poco, nuget-package

So I have my asp.net mvc wep app divided in multiple projects like MyProj.BusinessLogic, MyProj.Domain, MyProj,Web and MyProj.DAL.

I downloaded a NuGet package in the business logic layer that parse some articles (Read Sharp).
My problem is that the package is making an (POCO class) ReadSharp.Article after the parse (and I would like to keep it that way not just get some string from it's content) but that means i have to add the package to the other layers to use it (or at least to the domain layer and make a class MyArticle that would copy the content from the ReadSharp.Article class). But downloading the package to more than one layer dosen't look ok right?
Or I could take the code out of that package and move the Article to my domain and make the ReadSharp use my domain.

Or maybe there's another best practice. Please help.

Comment: Most probably that class would be a partial class, abstract it behind an interface in that case.

Comment: Sadly, it's not https://github.com/ceee/ReadSharp/blob/master/ReadSharp/Models/Article.cs ... but thanks for the answer

Comment: That is pure POCO class, use it as your own class. Unless the class needs some dependency from that library, exposing it across different layers is not a problem, that is what POCO is all about.

Comment: You mean I should download the package to my domain? or I should copy the class from the git to my domain and use it like th/at. Then would ReadSharp.Article be equal to MyProject.Domain.Article? Or I should write a constructor for MyProject.Domain.Article that takes a ReadSharp.Article and use it that way

Comment: I thought, after nuget package is installed, it created the class in your project. If the class is declared within that library, and you don't want it to be exposed directly, you'll need to create a different class and use it as a proxy class by manually creating an instance and initializing it with values from this `Article` class maybe.

Comment: ok :D ... thanks for answering. so there's no better practice than the proxy class

Comment: I'm afraid not. You may as well use an adapter class with internal constructor accepting `Article` class and providing proxy properties which delegates read/write directly to the wrapping instance. And expose this class. Same thing as proxy, but no copying around.